# Event after false condition inside if code goes to if clock instead of else block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have if else condition in which there are 3 checks all of them return false still code is going inside if block, which instead should go to else because all checks are failed.

If i test something like `if(false || false || false)` then this works fine but mine code isnt working like it should be.

```
state = { year : 2019, sortby : '', genres : [] }
nextState = { year : 2019, sortby : '', genres : [] };

console.log(state.year !== nextState.year);
console.log(state.sortby !== nextState.sortby);
console.log(!_.isEqual(state.genres.sort(), nextState.genres.sort()))

if(state.year !== nextState.year ||
   state.sortby !== nextState.sortBy ||
   !_.isEqual(state.genres.sort(), nextState.genres.sort())
){
  console.log("Inside if");
}else{
  console.log("Inside else");  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you write `state.sortby !== nextState.sortBy` instead of `state.sortby !== nextState.sortby`

Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

A typographical mistake

```
state = { year : 2019, sortby : '', genres : [] }
nextState = { year : 2019, sortby : '', genres : [] };

console.log(state.year !== nextState.year);
console.log(state.sortby !== nextState.sortby);
console.log(!_.isEqual(state.genres.sort(), nextState.genres.sort()))

if(state.year !== nextState.year ||
   state.sortby !== nextState.sortby ||
   !_.isEqual(state.genres.sort(), nextState.genres.sort())
){
  console.log("Inside if");
}else{
  console.log("Inside else");  
}
```